# I´m working with a function using triggers from firebase. Are there some reason about my triggers isn´t starting?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Someone could help me!!! I'm new using funtions of firestore google. I followed the documentation, my code is the next: Where my problema is that doen´t trigger the first function, may be something missing me, but I don´t know, I need your help please!!!.

```js
import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//This part should execute when I realize a update over firebase, but never is activated
exports.updateExistences = functions.database.ref('vouchers/{id}/cajas').onUpdate(async (change:any) => {
    // console.log(context.params);
    console.log('Before: ' +  JSON.stringify(change.before.child));
    console.log('After: ' + JSON.stringify(change.after.child));
});
//This trigger is activated and it is look like the trigger before but with firestore.document. So then I need to do triggered the trigger before, because according the documentation that way of trigger can be used with a path that return the data from the child node. 
exports.updateExistences1 = functions.firestore.document('vouchers/{id}')
.onUpdate((snapshot:any, context:any) => {
    // console.log(context.params);
    console.log('Before: ' +  JSON.stringify(snapshot.before.data()));
    console.log('After: ' + JSON.stringify(snapshot.after.data()));
    
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. And exactly... what did you try or research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about Cloud Firestore, but your first Cloud Function is declared to trigger on changes to the Realtime Database. Both databases are part of Firebase, but they're completely separate and Functions declared for one won't trigger for writes to the other.

If you want the first Function to trigger on an update to Firestore too, you'll have to declare it with a syntax similar to the second function: `functions.firestore.document('...path to document(s)...').onUpdate(`.

Comment: Ok. Frank, thank you so much for your answer. I´m going to try doing  that you commented.